# авторизация mysql + php session

Tags: php, mysql, сессия

Есть код

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    $log = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE name = '$log' AND value='$pass'");

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($numrows != 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $dbusername = $row['name'];
            $dbpassword = $row['value'];
         }

         if($log === $dbusername && $pass === $dbpassword){
             // старое место расположения
             session_start();
             $_SESSION['session_username'] = $dbusername;    
             /* Перенаправление браузера */
             header("Location: panel/index.php");
         }
    }

} 

if (isset($_SESSION['session_username'])){ 
    .... 
} 
else {
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0;URL=../enter">';
}
```

Первая часть кода работает до

```
$_SESSION['session_username'] = $dbusername;
```

почему-то сессия не записывается как с переменной `$log` , так и с `$dbusername`. Срабатывает редирект на

```
else {  echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0;URL=../enter">';}
```

Объясните, что не так?

Comment: у вас код вообще заходит в if где заполнение массива сессии? что пишет `print_r([$dbusername])` ?

Comment: Выкиньте книжку по которой php изучаете. Знания в ней уже протухли.

Comment: Array ( [0] => )

Comment: вы из базы выбираете всегда пару значений равных `$log` и `$pass`, зачем пытаться их потом из базы излекать и заносить в новые переменные `$dbusername` и `$dbpassword`. Посмотрите еще раз на логику своего кода, что то там не так. Помимо уже упомянутых выше архаизмов в виде `mysql_*`

Comment: вы сравниваете `$log == $dbusername`, но они у вас вообще всегда равны, по условию SQL запроса.

Comment: я исправил код, но почему сессия не устанавливается? $log содержит в себе значение 00001. Но сессия не принимает это значение

Comment: тогда покажите ваш исправленный код, и желательно нормально отформатированный.

Comment: @teran там была SQL инъекция, так что сравнивать `$log == $dbusername` действительно имело смысл - они могли быть не равны

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам нужно делать

> session_start();

всегда, до опроса переменной

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['session_username'])) {  // ....
```